# How to remove characters in specific columns and divide it with number in bash

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have file in this format:

```
2015;1;1;11;7;19805;"2";12892;12478;"0900";"0853";-7.00;17.00;"0910";"1712";11.00;"1723";-6.00;329.00;330.00;302.00;2475.00;
```

and i want remove quotation marks in columns 10, 11, 14, 15 and 17
And then divide numbers in this columns by 2400. So instead of 900 I'm expecting 0.375(=900/2400).

The final output should be in this format:

```
2015;1;1;11;7;19805;"2";12892;12478;0.375;0.355;-7.00;17.00;0.379;0.713;11.00;0.718;-6.00;329.00;330.00;302.00;2475.00;
```

I think I know how remove quotation marks, but I'm definitely lost with the rest... Or is it easier in python etc? Can you help me please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a gnu awk script for your situation:

**rq.awk**

```
BEGIN { FS=OFS=";"
        OFMT="%.6g" # change output decimal format
        # setup the field that should change:
        split("10 11 14 15 17", ndx, " ")
      }

      { for( k in ndx) {
          i=ndx[k]
          gsub(/"/, "", $i)
          $i=$i / 2400
        }
        # print all fields
        print
      }
```

Run it it like this: `awk -f rq.awk your_file` .

- in the beginning the fields are transferred into the array `ndx`,
- for each line: it loops over `ndx` and for each field in ndx:

  - substitutes the quotes with nothing with `gsub` function
  - does the division
- the single `print` outputs all fields including the modified fields

Answer (score 1):

Another way to hack this up with `awk`:

```
awk -F";" 'BEGIN{OFS=";"}function GSUB(F){gsub(/"/,"",$F);$F=$F/2400} {GSUB(10);GSUB(11);GSUB(14);GSUB(15);GSUB(1);print $0}' infile
```

That defines a function that substitutes out your double quotes for null, then divides by 2400. Then we just call it for each field and print the record. The `BEGIN` statement sets the Output Field Seperator `OFS` to a semicolon `;`